# Rewrite the equation of line $l$ in Cartesian form

Tags: vectors

The question asks to rewrite the following vector equation of line $l$ in **Cartesian form** $$l: \vec{r}= (4\vec{i}+0\vec{j}+2\vec{k}) + \lambda(3\vec{i}+\vec{j}+0\vec{k})$$ 
When I try to do it I result in the following Cartesian equation $$\frac{x-4}{3}=y=\frac{z-2}{0}$$
Is this correct?

Comment: Division by zero is not defined. So, you can write the equation as $$\frac{x-4}{3}=y,\quad z=2$$

Comment: This makes sense, thanks

Comment: Feel free to submit this as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that division by zero is not defined. So, you can write
$$\frac{x-4}3=y,\quad z=2.$$